# Benchmarktools' belapsed not working on symbol

Tags: julia, benchmarking

## Introduction

---

I have a directory with the following structure

```
--> Report
--> Problems
    --> PE_001
        --> Julia
            PE_001.naive.jl
            PE_001.jl
        --> Benchmarks
            test_001.txt
            test_002.txt
        --> Results
    --> PE_002
     .
     .
     .
    --> PE_XXX
--> Benchmark
```

I am attempting to iterate over all the Julia files and benchmark them against the benchmarking data located under the top directory `Benchmark`. I do not want to have to `cd` into each directory and run `@ belapsed` from the julia commandline to time every function individually.

To solve this problem I wrote the following code that is supposed to be located under `benchmarks` in the hierachy above. However I made it slightly simpler for illustrative purposes.

## Attempt at solution

---

**EDIT**: The code below does NOT follow the hierarchy outlined above. To quickly reproduce the error, the code below has been written in such a way that all the files can be placed in the same directory.

***benchmark.jl***

```
include("PE_002.jl")

using BenchmarkTools

function get_file_path(PE=1)
    current_folder = pwd()
    PE_folder = "/PE_" * lpad(string(PE),3,"0")
    dirname(pwd()) * "/Problems" * PE_folder * "/Julia"
end


function include_files(PE_dir)
    for filename in readdir(PE_dir)
        if !startswith(filename, "benchmark")
            filepath = PE_dir * "/" * filename
            @everywhere include($filepath)
        end
    end
end


function benchmark_files(PE_dir)
    for filename in readdir(PE_dir)
        if !startswith(filename, "benchmark")
            f = getfield(Main, Symbol(filename[1:end-3]))
            # Produces an error
            println(@belapsed f())
        end
    end
end

# Works
println(@belapsed PE_002())

PE_dir = pwd()
include_files(PE_dir)
benchmark_files(PE_dir)
```

**PE_002.jl**

```
function PE_002(limit = 4*10^6)
    a, b = 0, 2
    while b < limit
        a, b = b, 4 * b + a
    end
    div(a + b - 2, 4)
end
```

***PE_002_naive.jl***

```
function PE_002_naive(limit=4 * 10^6, F_1=1, F_2=2)
    total = 0
    while F_2 < limit
        if F_2 % 2 == 0
            total += F_2
        end
        F_1, F_2 = F_2, F_1 + F_2
    end
    total
end
```

**test_001.txt**

```
0*10**(2**0)
4*10**(2**0) 
4*10**(2**1)
4*10**(2**2)
4*10**(2**3) 
4*10**(2**4) 
4*10**(2**5) 
4*10**(2**6)
```

---

## Question

Interestingly enough including the file `PE_002` and then running `@ belapsed` works, however obtaining the filename from the directory, turning it into a symbol, then trying to time it with `@belapsed` fails.

I know `@elapsed works`, however, due to garbage collection it is not nearly accurate enough for my needs.

**Is there a simple way to benchmark all files in a remote directory using BenchmarkTools or similar tools as accurate?**

All I need is a single number representing mean / average running time from each file.

EDIT 2: Per request I have included the full error message below

```
~/P/M/Julia-belaps ❯❯❯ julia benchmark.jl

9.495495495495496e-9
ERROR: LoadError: UndefVarError: f not defined
Stacktrace:
 [1] ##core#665() at /home/oisov/.julia/v0.6/BenchmarkTools/src/execution.jl:290
 [2] ##sample#666(::BenchmarkTools.Parameters) at /home/oisov/.julia/v0.6/BenchmarkTools/src/execution.jl:296
 [3] #_run#6(::Bool, ::String, ::Array{Any,1}, ::Function, ::BenchmarkTools.Benchmark{Symbol("##benchmark#664")}, ::BenchmarkTools.Parameters) at /home/oisov/.julia/v0.6/BenchmarkTools/src/execution.jl:324
 [4] (::BenchmarkTools.#kw##_run)(::Array{Any,1}, ::BenchmarkTools.#_run, ::BenchmarkTools.Benchmark{Symbol("##benchmark#664")}, ::BenchmarkTools.Parameters) at ./<missing>:0
 [5] anonymous at ./<missing>:?
 [6] #run_result#16(::Array{Any,1}, ::Function, ::BenchmarkTools.Benchmark{Symbol("##benchmark#664")}, ::BenchmarkTools.Parameters) at /home/oisov/.julia/v0.6/BenchmarkTools/src/execution.jl:40
 [7] (::BenchmarkTools.#kw##run_result)(::Array{Any,1}, ::BenchmarkTools.#run_result, ::BenchmarkTools.Benchmark{Symbol("##benchmark#664")}, ::BenchmarkTools.Parameters) at ./<missing>:0
 [8] #run#17(::Array{Any,1}, ::Function, ::BenchmarkTools.Benchmark{Symbol("##benchmark#664")}, ::BenchmarkTools.Parameters) at /home/oisov/.julia/v0.6/BenchmarkTools/src/execution.jl:43
 [9] (::Base.#kw##run)(::Array{Any,1}, ::Base.#run, ::BenchmarkTools.Benchmark{Symbol("##benchmark#664")}, ::BenchmarkTools.Parameters) at ./<missing>:0 (repeats 2 times)
 [10] macro expansion at /home/oisov/.julia/v0.6/BenchmarkTools/src/execution.jl:208 [inlined]
 [11] benchmark_files(::String) at /home/oisov/Programming/Misc/Julia-belaps/benchmark.jl:26
 [12] include_from_node1(::String) at ./loading.jl:569
 [13] include(::String) at ./sysimg.jl:14
 [14] process_options(::Base.JLOptions) at ./client.jl:305
 [15] _start() at ./client.jl:371
while loading /home/oisov/Programming/Misc/Julia-belaps/benchmark.jl, in expression starting on line 36
```

Comment: Be helpful to see the error?

Comment: Added errormessage

Comment: I tried to build a MWE (or minimum failing example), but it works fine. ```using BenchmarkTools

fname = "stackexchange46809845_f.jl"
funstr = """myfun() = rand(1000)"""
open(fname,"w") do f
    write(f,funstr)
end
include(fname)

function_name = :myfun
f=getfield(Main, function_name)

@belapsed myfun()
@belapsed f()```

Comment: @gggg Did you try to include it from a neighbor directory?

Comment: Yes it still works for me, did you try my example? Here is an updated version as a gist for easier copy/paste.  https://gist.github.com/ggggggggg/83340e3c54cb0cc0cbc51f5d1dcd74cd

Comment: @gggg Thanks a bunch for trying to help me. Yes, I tried your version. Look at line 12, `function_name = :myfun` you are hardcoding in the name of the function in the file. However, in my case my main function is called the same as the filename. 

The main problem is running BenchmarkTools against a function defined as a symbol from a string. If the function name never changes then your solution works.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the difference. I updated the gist to define the function name as a symbol derived from a String, it still works. Can you modify my example to fail in the same way yours does? It's more self contained so it's easier to think about.

Comment: I agree you example is easier to follow, and am sorry that I was not able to construct it myself. Here is the updated gist of where it fails: https://gist.github.com/Oisov/64346afba5f6e6361619965db8ccc70c
Seems we have been able to pinpoint the error. It has to do with the `for loop`. I changed the function name to match the filename. The loop clearly is able to print out the content of the function in the file, but not benchmark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `println(@belapsed f())` to `println(@belapsed $f())`. I can't fully explain it, but [here is a link to the relevant part of the docs.](https://github.com/JuliaCI/BenchmarkTools.jl/blob/master/doc/manual.md#interpolating-values-into-benchmark-expressions)

Comment: That worked like a charm. Thanks so much for your patience!